# remove 'new' action from backend application module, symfony

Tags: php, symfony1, admin, generator

I have created a module in backend application. need to remove the 'new' action, but unfortunately i don't know how to remove this from generator.yml :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specifiy the actions available on the various views, in this case the list view. I have removed the options from the generator config that are not applicable.

```
  # generator.yml
  generator:
    class: sfDoctrineGenerator
    param:
      config:
        list:
          actions:
            {}
```

By setting an empty array on the list:actions setting you can remove the link to the new action.

See 'Lists' section at http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/en/06-Admin-Generator#chapter_06_actions